I invested thru a friend
My friend told me a new company was launching and I invested $300. There were 29 investors. The company wants me to verify my account by sending money on same Bitcoin wallet I used when I sent the money to my friend so he could invest it. I have used this wallet address a few times to send Bitcoin to my friend.
To proceed with the verification, a $1,300 Bitcoin transfer is required.
This transfer needs to be made from the same Cash App wallet you used to deposit funds into the account. The reason for this is to validate that the same person who made the original investment is now claiming the
funds, ensuring the security of the transaction.
Here's how the process works:

You will transfer $1,300 in Bitcoin to the same wallet you initially used for your deposit.

Once the transfer is complete, the amount will show immediately in your available balance within the account.

This transaction will serve as confirmation of your identity and ownership of the account.

After the transfer is successfully verified, you will receive a call from our team to confirm your identity using the information we have on file.


I trusted my friend that this is legit but I'm scared! My question is how would this company NOW have the wallet address I used many times to send Bitcoin to my friend??? Could my friend be involved in a scam also???

I don't see a specific question here, but this seems like a scam considering the use of Bitcoin, the supposed verification transfer, and the theory that you could invest in a company with $300 via Bitcoin with 29 people (investment scam? advance fee scam? identity theft? all of those, maybe?). Is this "account" from the official page of a reputable brokerage or some random page? Also, I really would not suggest giving information to "confirm your identity". Random people (especially random DMs) claiming to be able to recover lost funds are probably also scams. See "recovery scam".

I trusted my friend that this is legit but I'm scared! My question is how would this company NOW have the wallet address I used many times to send Bitcoin to my friend??? Could my friend be involved in a scam also???

I'm not sure on the first question. For the second question, did this friend reach out to you online? Or have you known them a long time and met them in person? It's not unheard of for scammers to interact with people online enough to convince a victim that they're friends, when really they've just been trying to scam you the whole time. It's also possible your friend just got scammed too. Hard to say without more information, although I would not send any more crypto. Can you share anything about this company or how you access your account?

They send me emails then I can check my acct. This is the web site of you could please let me know if this is a scam. https://group.westerncf.top/login.php

It's a scam. One indicator (but there are plenty of others) is the phone number on the about page. (123) 456-7890 is not a legitimate number.
